# Prove the inequalities $|e^{x}-1|\leq e^{|x|}-1\leq |x|e^{|x|}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $|e^{x}-1|\leq e^{|x|}-1\leq |x|e^{|x|}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$. I did this by Maclaurin series of $e^x$,
$$|e^{x}-1|\leq |x|+\frac{|x|^2}{2!}+\frac{|x|^3}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^{4})=e^{|x|}-1 \\
\leq |x|^2+\frac{|x|^3}{2!}+\frac{|x|^4}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^{5})=|x|e^{|x|}.$$
My teacher disliked the last inequality, and I don't know why. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: x<1 is possible which would cause some problems imo

Comment: @avz2611 If deleting the big oh notation, the inequality like $|x|\leq |x|^2$ would be senseless for $0<x<1$. But I don't see why it's relevant as I used the big oh notation.

Comment: $|x|^2+\frac{|x|^3}{2!}+\frac{|x|^4}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^{5}) = |x|e^(|x|)-1 \neq |x|e^{|x|} $ But $|x|+ |x|^2+\frac{|x|^3}{2!}+\frac{|x|^4}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^{5}) = |x|e^{|x|} $ does

Comment: Big-oh notation gives information about a local property, but you're not showing something locally, you're trying to prove an inequality, over (at least) an interval.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{|x|}-1\leq |x|e^{|x|}\iff 1-e^{-|x|}\le|x|\iff\int_0^{|x|}e^{-t}\,dt\le\int_0^{|x|}1\,dt$$

which is clearly true because $e^{-t}\le1$ for $t\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

Reason why one's argument is invalid:

The last inequality shows something untrue:
$$\frac{|x|^3}{2!}+\frac{|x|^4}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(|x|^{5})=|x|e^{|x|}-|x|$$

If one try to use $$e^{|x|}-1\leq e^{|x|} \leq |x|e^{|x|}$$
It is invalid because the last inequality when $x = 0.5$ does not hold.

Here is my solution:
Let u = |x| ($u\geq 0$), then the inequality
$$e^{|x|}-1\leq |x|e^{|x|}\\ \iff e^u-1 \leq ue^u$$

One's goal is to show $e^u-1 \leq ue^u$ holds for all $u\geq0 $

Designate function $f(x) := e^x-xe^x-1$ $ x \in [0,+\infty]$

$f'(x) = e^x-(e^x+xe^x) = -xe^x$

Which means $f'(x)\leq0$ for all  $ x \in [0,+\infty]$

Therefore f(x) is decreasing on $ [0,+\infty] \iff$ $f(0)$ is maximum over interval$ [0,+\infty] $

Since $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) = e^x-xe^x-1 \leq 0 $ for all $x\in[0,+\infty]$

=> $e^x-1 \leq xe^x$ which is one's goal.

Qed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use some steps in between:
\begin{align*}
e^{| x| } - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^n}{n!} = | x | \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \frac{1}{n!} \le |x| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = |x| e^{|x|}
\end{align*}
as $\frac{1}{n!} \le 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.
Note that after the inequality we have start with a  factor $|x|$ instead of $|x|^2$ as the Maclaurin series of $\exp(|x|)$ start with a $1$ and not with $|x|$.